# What kind of pets can I keep in my house?

Tags: taharah, pets

Islam considers cleanliness very important, and keeping some kind of pets can sometimes be a burden in terms of cleanliness. This looks like a contradiction to me.

Is there a law about keeping pets?  Did Rasulallah (S) keep any pet?

Comment: I think Everything except Dogs...

Answer (score 12):

You can keep permissible animals as pets as long as you treat and feed them properly. And the permissible animals are many like fish, birds, cats. Impermissible from what I know are only dogs because Islam has forbidden keeping dogs except guard dogs and hunting dogs.

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said,

> He who keeps a dog, will lose out of his good deeds equal to one Qirat every day, except one who keeps it for guarding the fields or the herd.

[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

In a narration of Muslim, the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) is reported to have said:

> He who keeps a dog for any reason other than to guard his property (lands) or his flock of sheep, his good deeds equal to two Qirat will be deducted every day.

and Narrated by al-Bukhaari (3225) and Muslim (2106) that

> “The angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog.”

Abu Hurayrah was so called because of a cat which used to accompany him.

> Al-Bukhaari (6203) and Muslim (2150) narrated that Anas (may Allaah be
>   pleased with him) said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be
>   upon him) was the best of people in attitude. I had a brother who was
>   called Abu ‘Umayr. He (the narrator) said: I think he said: He was a
>   weanling. When the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah
>   be upon him) came and saw him, he said: “Abu ‘Umayr, what happened to
>   the nughayr (nightingale)?” He used to play with it.

The above hadeeth shows it is also permissible to keep birds as pets and children can play with them.

It is also known that the saliva of cats is not impure (naajis):

> Because of the report narrated in Sunan Abi Dawood and elsewhere,
>   which says that a woman brought some hareesah (a kind of food) to
>   ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) and found her praying.
>   (‘Aa’ishah) gestured to her that she should put it down. Then a cat
>   came and ate some of it. When ‘Aa’ishah had finished praying, she ate
>   from where the cat had eaten and said, “The Messenger of Allaah (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘They (cats) are not naajis
>   (impure), rather they are among those who go around among you
>   (al-tawwaafeena ‘alaykum).’ I saw the Messenger of Allaah (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) doing wudoo’ with water from which a
>   cat had drunk.”

What is impermissible is showing extravagance with animals i.e. spending lot of money on beautifying them and such.

Comment: @Songo There is also another hadeeth which prohibits keeping dogs for anything other than hunting and such : Muslim (2978) narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever keeps a dog that is not a dog for hunting, herding livestock or farming, two qiraats will be deducted from his reward each day.” Hence it is haraam to keep dog for any other purpose other than the exceptional cases mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

According to Jafari Fiqh Pets are all allowed, except that one must be careful about such pets which
are NAJIS.  Secondly Islam enjoins upon us to look after them well.  If we
cannot, then they must be released.

Islamically there is no problem in keeping a guard dog on your premises.
Since dogs (and pigs) are from Najisul `ayn (inherently impure) animals, you
will have to make sure that they do not lick the areas which are always
supposed to remain tahir, such as place of prayers, place where sacred
things like the Holy Qur'an and sajdagha (turbah) are kept. Also, do not eat
or drink from the utensils which have been licked by the dog, unless you
have cleansed it by rubbing with wet clean earth and then washing it with
water. Sometimes your dog will cling to your clothes (say, pants) then such
clothes should not be worn for salat.

---

**References:**

- Islamic Law by Syd Seestani, Elements of Islamic Studies by S.
  S. Akhtar Rizvi, commentaries to surah 18 of the Qur'an
- [www.al-islam.org (1)](http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/aalimnetwork/msg00700.html)
- [www.al-islam.org (2)](http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/aalimnetwork/msg00256.html)

Answer (score 2):

Cat is good. Rasulullah (May Salat and Salam be upon him) said it is an household item and won't cancel/interrupt your salat when near.

Comment: I think the downvote for no reference, atleast they could've reminded him!

Answer (score -1):

Pets are allowed but except dogs who ever has a dog in their house every day loose out his deed equal to a qirat(qirat is equal to a size of a mountain) 
But cats, fish, turtle etc.  Are allowed

Comment: Your answer lacks refrences so please add references to support your statement and read our help