# Is breeding dogs at home permissible in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, pets

Assume that I have dogs and I'm breeding them. They enter my home and my room where I pray.

Is that permissible in Islam?

And if I don't let them enter my room but let them stay in the rest of the house, is that Halal?

Comment: Related: [What kind of pets can I keep in my house?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/610/what-kind-of-pets-can-i-keep-in-my-house).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two conditions in dog breeding:

**1) If the protection of farm or to protect the general.**

**2) If used for hunting or used in security and police**

Except that, It is not permissible, and detract from wage work.

> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   ‏:‏ ‏"‏من أمسك كلبًا فإنه ينقص كل يوم من عمله قيراط إلا كلب حرث أو
>   ماشية‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏ وفي رواية لمسلم‏:‏ ‏"‏من اقتنى كلبًا
>   ليس بكلب صيد، ولا ماشية ولا أرض، فإنه ينقص من أجره قيراطان كل يوم‏"‏‏
>
> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of
>   Allah (PBUH) said, "He who keeps a dog, will lose out of his good
>   deeds equal to one Qirat every day, except one who keeps it for
>   guarding the fields or the herd."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> In a narration of Muslim, the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) is reported to
>   have said: "He who keeps a dog for any reason other than to guard his
>   property (lands) or his flock of sheep, his good deeds equal to two
>   Qirat will be deducted every day."

And angels do not enter a house that it(dog) was in this house.

> وعن أبي طلحة رضي الله عنه أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏لا
>   تدخل الملائكة بيتًا فيه كلب ولا صورة‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> Abu Talhah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of
>   Allah (PBUH) said, "The angels do not enter a house in which there is
>   a dog or a portrait."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

With the knowledge, if to touch the human dog, you should wash the custom to touch the dogs
That is, washed with water and 7 times, including once with dust.

Comment: I think you mean *hunting*, not fishing.

Comment: I intended fishing in general and not fishing fish :)
You can edit these kind of mistakes :)

Comment: Well it's only called fishing when it's for fish, otherwise it's called hunting. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Yes you are right, not Be careful :(. thanks for note

Comment: salam wahliakoum, hi I just to know what that mean qirat in this hadith?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but now I realized your coment
qirat is Measure unit used by jewelry makers for weight precious stones.The word is derived from the Arab word meaning grain or seeds.

Carat weighs 200 milligrams or 0.2 grams.

Answer (score 2):

Angels do not enter places where there is a dog, The Prophet Naha(inhibition) and he said(Peace be upon him):

> Abu Talhah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of
>   Allah (Peace be upon him) said, "The angels do not enter a house in which there is a
>   dog or a portrait."
>
> وعن أبي طلحة رضي الله عنه أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏
>   "‏لا تدخل الملائكة بيتًا فيه كلب ولا صورة‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

[Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18#174)

You see from Hadith that the angels do not enter these houses and you see that the portrait take the same rule.

And the Prophet said too:

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of
>   Allah (Peace be upon him) said, "Angels do not accompany the travellers who have with
>   them a dog or a bell."
>
> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏:‏
>   ‏ "‏لا تصحب الملائكة رفقة كلب أو جرس‏"‏‏.‏
>
> [Muslim].

[Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18#180)