# Keeping a animal as a pet

Tags: halal-haram, pets

I'm asking this this because I heard not all animals are allowed to be kept as pets and I was wondering if I'm allowed to keep an African gray parrot or macaw parrot any color or to have any kind of fish as pet such as: Lionfish,angler fish etc because I saw some people having those kind of fish at home as pets

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Please do not use comments for answering questions or debating controversial points. Comments are intended for *seeking clarification* or *constructive criticism* of the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference to a post from ***[Islam questions](https://islamqa.info)*** and ***[islam stackexchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/610/what-kind-of-pets-can-i-keep-in-my-house)***

> Keeping and raising pets is something that is permitted in Islam and there is nothing wrong with it.

So keeping permissible animals, so long as you do not neglect them, is something which is permitted and it may even be one of the means of earning reward, as the

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, “In every living being there is reward.”

But if you keep animals and neglect and abuse them, it may be one of the means that lead to sin and the threat of Hell, as in the hadeeth about the woman who neglected her cat until it died.

> Al-Bukhaari and Muslim narrated that Anas said:
>
> "The Prophet (ﷺ) was the best of people in attitude. I had a brother who was called Abu 'Umayr. He said:  He was a weanling. When the Messenger of Allaah came and saw him, he said: `“Abu ‘Umayr, what happened to the nughayr (nightingale)?” He used to play with it".

Al-Haafiz Ibn Hajar said:

> "It indicates that it is permissible for children to play with birds, and it is permissible to spend money on permissible things that will entertain children, and it is permissible to keep birds in cages and the like, and to clip the wings of birds, because one or the other must have been done in the case of `Abu ‘Umayr’s bird`, and whichever is the case, the other comes under the same ruling.."

With regard to the conditions and guidelines on keeping animals, these include the following:

1. The animal that is kept **should not be a dog**, because Islam has
   forbidden keeping dogs **except guard dogs and hunting dogs**.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: “The angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari and Muslim.

2. The animal must be treated kindly. If a Muslim keeps an animal, he
   must provide it with proper food and drink, and not cause it any
   harm or injury by mistreating it or using it for target practice or
   making animals fight one another, or exposing it to heat or cold.

On this basis, there is nothing wrong with your keeping **parrot** or **fish** as you mentioned in your question, so long as you take care of feeding them and avoiding anything that could cause their death.

**NOTE**

It is permissible to keep pets, regardless of whether they are birds, fish, reptiles or any other animal except pigs and dogs. It will not be permissible to keep an animal which may cause harm neither is it permissible to cause any harm to an animal.

It is permissible to keep pretty birds and the like in cages, especially if that is to enjoy looking at them or listening to their voices, subject to the condition that you give them food and drink.

Answer (score 0):

بسم الله       
Keeping a animal as a pet.

```
what the animal that is not allowed in Islam to keep as pets ?
```

- Pigs because it's dirty
- Dogs if it is not for hunting or security purpose

> قوله سبحانه وتعالى: ﴿ إِنَّمَا حَرَّمَ عَلَيْكُمُ الْمَيْتَةَ
> وَالدَّمَ وَلَحْمَ الْخِنْزِيرِ وَمَا أُهِلَّ بِهِ لِغَيْرِ الله ﴾
>
> He has only forbidden to you dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine,
> and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah . But whoever is
> forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its
> limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and
> Merciful.

the pigs are not allowed because it's dirty
dogs in hadith are also not allowed

> وَحَدَّثَنِي مَالِكٌ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُمَرَ،
> أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ مَنِ اقْتَنَى
> كَلْبًا إِلاَّ كَلْبًا ضَارِيًا أَوْ كَلْبَ مَاشِيَةٍ نَقَصَ مِنْ
> عَمَلِهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ قِيرَاطَانِ ‏
>
> Malik related to me from Nafi from Abdullah ibn Umar that the
> Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said,
> "Whoever acquires a dog other than a sheepdog or hunting dog, will
> have two qirats deducted from the reward of his good actions every
> day.

**Animals that islam allowed to kill**

"**Rats and mice, scorpions, crows(black and white), kites and wild dogs.**"

> حَدَّثَنِي عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ،
> أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ خَمْسٌ فَوَاسِقُ
> يُقْتَلْنَ فِي الْحَرَمِ الْفَأْرَةُ وَالْعَقْرَبُ وَالْغُرَابُ
> وَالْحِدَأَةُ وَالْكَلْبُ الْعَقُورُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Yahya related to me from Malik from Hisham ibn Urwa from his father
> that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace,
> said, "There are five trespassers that can be killed in the Haram:
> rats and mice, scorpions, crows, kites and wild dogs."
>
> In another hadith Gecko is allowed to kill it
>
> عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال‏:‏ قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏:‏
> “من قتل وزغة في أول ضربة فله كذا وكذا حسنة،ومن قتلها في الضربة
> الثانية، فله كذا وكذا حسنة، ودون الأول وإن قتلها في الضربة الثالثة،
> فله كذا وكذا حسنة” ‏(‏‏(‏رواه مسلم‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏ وفي رواية‏:‏ ‏ "‏من قتل
> وزغاً في أول ضربة، كتب له مائة حسنة، وفى الثانية دون ذلك، وفى الثالثة
> دون ذلك‏"‏
>
> Another narration is: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "If anyone
> kills a Gecko with the first blow, a hundred good deeds will be
> recorded for him; less than that will be recorded for him if he kills
> it at the second blow, and still less rewards will be recorded for him
> if he kills it at the third blow."

[image]

so if Islam allow you to kill it, so you should not keep it as a pets
**(there are some condition to kill these animals I did not mention it here)**

**Animals that Islam allowed to keep it as pets**

**Cats**

> قَالَ إِنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّهَا
> لَيْسَتْ بِنَجَسٍ إِنَّمَا هِيَ مِنَ الطَّوَّافِينَ عَلَيْكُمْ أَوِ
> الطَّوَّافَاتِ ‏"‏
>
> Yahya related to me from Malik from Ishaq ibn Abdullah ibn Abi Talha
> from Humayda bint Abi Ubayda ibn Farwa that her maternal aunt Kabsha
> bint Kab ibn Malik, who was the wife of the son of Abu Qatada
> al-Ansari, told her that once Abu Qatada was visiting her and she
> poured out some water for him to do wudu with. Just then a cat came to
> drink from it, so he tilted the vessel towards it to let it drink.
> Kabsha continued, "He saw me looking at him and said, 'Are you
> surprised, daughter of my brother?' I said, 'Yes.' He replied that the
> Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said,
> cats are not impure. They intermingle with you .' "
>
> Yahya said that Malik said, "There is no harm in that unless one sees
> impurities on the cat's mouth."

**birds**

حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى، قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنَا سُلَيْمَانُ بْنُ الْمُغِيرَةِ، عَنْ ثَابِتٍ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ قَالَ‏:‏ دَخَلَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَرَأَى ابْنًا لأَبِي طَلْحَةَ يُقَالُ لَهُ‏:‏ أَبُو عُمَيْرٍ، وَكَانَ لَهُ نُغَيْرٌ يَلْعَبُ بِهِ، فَقَالَ‏:‏ يَا أَبَا عُمَيْرٍ، مَا فَعَلَ أَوْ، أَيْنَ، النُّغَيْرُ‏؟‏‏.

> Anas said, "The Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, came
> in and saw a son of Abu Talha's called Abu 'Umayr. He had a sparrow
> which he used to play with." He said, "Abu 'Umayr, what happened to
> (or where is) the little sparrow?'"

Now we come to animals that there is no Hadith about it what should I do with it
If it is wild animal like tiger youcan keep it but not in society because these animals sometimes can not be control if he will keep it away from people and the country law allow keeping it there is no problem in keep it in safe house

in the end you it it preferable not keep animal that there is no benefit from it in hunting or to keep is as pets like tiger you will spend money and time that you can spend it in something else which gives you benefits.

والله اعلم

Comment: And is there a verse from Quran that says:It is not allowed to have pigs as pets?

Comment: No there is not verse in Quran that says it is not allowed to keep it as pets but all of as we know that pigs eat it own faeces and in Islam you and your house should be clean if there is pigs in the environment you are living in how it can be clean if there is pigs .

Comment: Your response is filled with errors. You quoted a Hadith that states that certain animals should be killed around the vicinity of the Haram Mosque, yet you assume that this must mean that such animals shouldn't be pets. You also misquote the Quran when it says do not eat flesh of swine and conclude that it means not to keep pigs as pets, etc. If I was you, I'd delete the whole reponse. Too many errors, and if you're a Muslim you're trespassing on Divine Legalities where you start making Halal things Haram and vice versa. Be careful.

Comment: I don't know why you are upset this is the Hadith about killing it when you are in Ihram or otherwise.  (https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/76) and in Islam there is something call Discretion of judgments like Heroin is not mention in Quran so I can look for similar Verse that describe thing that harms body and based on that you decide according to it effects  (https://quran.com/5/90?translations=29)   <br> so if Islam allow me to kill it that's mean it's hurts or cause problem to me will worship and I mention there are some condition to kill it

Comment: (http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=122702) you can look here also when you don't have Islamic background don't be upset.(Allah Knows best)

Comment: So,also if I wish to have a scorpion as my pet,then I can?Coz I've seen a Christian women having many scorpions on her while she is in bed with belly up to,just like her guardians and they do not do any harm to her only protect her,like if a fly were to come to her belly or anything then one of those scorpions will attack that fly or something in order to protect her,and hat was amazing.I was wonder if scorpions are trainable animals?

Comment: I mention up scorpion is one of the five animals that most Imam says you should not keep it as pets because Islam allow you to kill it and not allow you to use it like pigs, is not allowed to keep it (https://islamqa.info/ar/132566)

Comment: I know that every species has its own purpose of living on life,just we have our purpose and our purpose is to worship God alone and to do good deeds and also scorpions have there purpose,right?

Comment: why do you think Islam allow to kill scorpions ?

Comment: Ooo,so islam allows to kill a scorpion when you see attacking you then you as self defense,but other wise,nu you can't kill,right?

Comment: I don't know, but you should not search for scorpions just to kill them, Do you live in village or in city

Comment: @YousefAli Of course,I live in a city

Comment: Do you find scorpions in your city ,because  in my whole life I didn't see even one ,It lives in deserts and semi-arid regions

Comment: @YousefAli Neither me,and of course I don't find scorpions in the city.